# Выход - false; Должно быть - true;

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
let x = 1;
let y = 0;
if([x, y] == [1, 0] || [x, y] == [0, 1]){
    console.log("s");
}
```

B if должно быть true, но консоль говорит , что false. Почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Не должно.*

Потому что сравнение `==` массивов (ссылочного типа данных) сравнивает ссылки, а они разные.

```js
let x = 1;
let y = 0;

console.log([x, y] == [1, 0]);
console.log([x, y] == [0, 1]);

if([x, y] == [1, 0] || [x, y] == [0, 1]){
    console.log("s");
}
```